# Improving a regular expression for validating payment amount

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, payment

I would like to improve the regular expression for validating payment amounts in the following function to allow at most one leading zero, but only if it also contains two decimal places, and is not 0.00 (thereby making the call to parseFloat moot)

```
function isValidPaymentAmount(paymentAmt) {
    return /^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/.test(paymentAmt) && parseFloat(paymentAmt) > 0;
}
```

Comment: would `0.0099` be a valid argument in your case?

Comment: *At most one leading zero, but only if it also contains two decimal places* sounds like it would match `0111.00`--really?

Comment: I suspect a mere `/^(?!0+\.0+$)\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$/` will do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your idea allows multiple leading zeros such as `000`

Comment: It means, you can use [`^(?!0)\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/zK9aU3/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a positive non-zero amount, you need to extend your option so that it won't allow any two digits after a leading zero, so something like:

```
^((0?\.((0[1-9])|[1-9]\d))|([1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?))$
```

Comment: I've deleted my answer which I'm guessing you down-voted since you commented on one thing it didn't work for, but really, I did almost all the legwork, and you just tweaked the following: `/^((0?\.((0[1-9])|\d{2}))|([1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?))$/`

Answer (score 0):

Try just writing it out:

```
/^((0\.\d\d)|([1-9]\d*(\.\d\d)?))$/
```

But how to omit `0.00`? You could do a separate check. If you really want to do it with regexp, then that part could be written, instead of `\d\d`, as

```
[1-9]\d|\d[1-9]
```

so

```
/^((0\.([1-9]\d|\d[1-9]))|[1-9]\d*(\.\d\d)?)$/
```

Comment: Your second regex allows `0.0111111`

Comment: Hopefully fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this as:

```
^(0?[1-9]\d*\.\d\d|[1-9]\d*)$
```

The first part of the alternation handles leading zeros and decimals, with the leading zero being optional, and the second part of the alternation deals with whole numbers. If you want to allow zero as an input, then you can add a second alternation:

```
^(0?[1-9]\d*\.\d\d|[1-9]\d*|0)$
```

Answer (score -1):

`/^((0?\.((0[1-9])|\d{2}))|([1-9]\d*(\.\d{2})?))$/`

See: https://regex101.com/r/gI8mN4/1

Comment: Yeah I though I had precluded 0.00 but I posted this rather hastily before leaving work